# Apache Flink: count window return a GlobalWindow

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

when I apply the countWindow method to a KeyedStream, I get back a GlobalWindow and not a CountWindow. Does anyone know why? I can't find anything in the Flink documentation.

Thanks!

```
WindowedStream<Share, String, GlobalWindow> windowedStream2 = keyed.countWindow(100, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting windows in Flink's DataStream API are simple enough that they don't require a window assigner with any smarts beyond what the basic `GlobalWindow` window assigner does -- which is to put every event in *the* window. Here's the implementation you are using:

```java
/**
 * Windows this {@code KeyedStream} into sliding count windows.
 *
 * @param size The size of the windows in number of elements.
 * @param slide The slide interval in number of elements.
 */
public WindowedStream<T, KEY, GlobalWindow> countWindow(long size, long slide) {
    return window(GlobalWindows.create())
            .evictor(CountEvictor.of(size))
            .trigger(CountTrigger.of(slide));
}
```

`CountWindow` and its associated classes are part of the Table API runtime, and aren't used by the DataStream API.